# Redirect users to account page if signed-in

Tags: php, redirect

I'm creating a login system for my site and was wondering if anyone could help me with a problem? I would like for people who are already logged in that go onto the signup page to be redirected to the your account page.

I have tried this, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) { 
    header("location: youraccount"); 
} else {
    header("location: signup"); 
    exit();
} 
?>
```

---

I have managed to do it after a bit off messing around.

This is what finally worked for me-

```
<?php 
if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) { 
    header('Location: youraccount?id=' . $userid . '');
    exit(); 
} 
?>
```

Comment: What is the actual problem? Do you get a 404 (which would be solved by the answers already posted) or is it a Session problem that you get redirected to the wrong page? "It doesn't seem to work" is not really a good explanation.

Comment: The page just wasn't loading correctly. When I removed the    header("location: signup");  - it worked. I think that it was because the page was just constantly reloading.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect to any of "youraccount.php" and "signup.php" pages, you must give the ".php" extension and ensure the files are in the same directory. If they are not in same directory use complete URL path. See [Header](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_header.asp) for more details

Like:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) { 
    header("location: youraccount.php"); 
} else {
    header("location: signup.php"); 
    exit(); 
} 
?>
```

Answer (score -3):

You have to use a complete URL:

like Location: `header('Location: http://www.example.com/');`

Be sure to not output anything before modifying the header or it won't work.

[Documentation for header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).